# Refactoring mutually exclusive booleans in Java

Tags: java, enums, int, boolean, refactoring

Lets say "we" have some boolean flags that dictate how an app behaves at any given time... anything from how touches are handled to what happens in onPause().

```
boolean touchMode_BlockAllExceptCreateNew = false;
boolean touchMode_UserIsEditting = false;
boolean touchMode_Animation4IsTakingPlace = false;
```

There *could* be a potentially infinite number of these little guys. :)

These "states" are mutually exclusive -- only one can or should be legally happening at a time.

So... isn't there some clever way of enforcing that mutual exclusivity by combining them into one variable?

Is using an Enum pretty much the only way to do this?  Like this:

```
private enum TouchMode {
    flibbidyInProgress,
    deletePending,
    userIsEditting,
    jumpingJacks,
    recyclerViewIsOpen,
    normal // none
}

TouchMode currentTouchMode = TouchMode.normal;

private void changeTouchMode(TouchMode desiredTouchMode) {

    boolean undesirableCondition1 = (desiredTouchMode == currentTouchMode);
    boolean undesirableCondition2 = (desiredTouchMode != TouchMode.normal 
            && currentTouchMode != TouchMode.normal);

    if (undesirableCondition1 | undesirableCondition2) {
        Log.e("XXX", ">> ILLEGAL TOUCHMODE REQUEST! <<");
        Log.e("XXX", "requested: " + desiredTouchMode
                + ", current: " + currentTouchMode);
    } else {
        currentTouchMode = desiredTouchMode;
    }

}
```

I thought I had seen some clever way of making the 'currentTouchMode' an int and assigning hex constants to it.

Comment: You could also take a look at the `State` pattern

Answer (score 1):

You should read about `Strategy` OOP pattern, it's used for similar cases.
Here is some useful links:

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java)

[refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy)

If shortly - you should create class hierarchy with common interface and class-specific implementations for each `TouchMode` (f.e. `AnimationTouch`, `EditionTouch`, etc.). Then you should use them via your common interface.